# How can I make Google Chrome tabs sharper?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

[Picture about my chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soZjd.png) I've Ubuntu 16.04 and my problem is in Google Chrome (not chromium) the tabs fonts are blur. 
I tried change antialiasing in unity tweak, so my fonts are sharper in ubuntu, expect google chrome. Disturb my eyes.
Also tried go to *chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write* and was looking for "DirectWrite" but i didn't find. So how can I get sharper fonts?

Comment: There's an extension for Chrome to it, but I think its too old: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-rendering-enhancer/hmbmmdjlcdediglgfcdkhinjdelkiock. Could you try it?

Comment: Please edit your question and post a screenshot of your browser.

Comment: I tried this extension, i dont see any changes. I posted a screenshot of my browser. I used windows 10 before, and yesterday I installed ubuntu, in windows 10 it was sharp. I hope you see the blur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
--disable-directwrite-for-ui
```

Comment: Any reference for that?

Comment: And also give a little bit more explanation on how / where to use those switches.